# IndexError: index 54 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 48

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keras, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to fetch the predicted sentiment score and determine whether the text is positive or negative. But while predicting the values I am getting an array sequence of scores and throws the following error.

```
import json
f = open(("/content/trending_tweets.json"), "r+")
data = f.read()
for x in data.split("\n"):
    strlist = "[" + x + "]"
    datalist = json.loads(strlist)
    for y in datalist:
        f = open('/content/user_lookup_data.json', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
        print(y["user"]["screen_name"])
        screen_name = ('@' + y["user"]["screen_name"])
        file_name ='/content/user_timeline/'  + screen_name + '_tweets.csv'
        user_timeline_data = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep='\t', lineterminator='\n',encoding='latin')
        user_timeline_data = (user_timeline_data['tweet'])
        print(len(user_timeline_data))
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Text', 'Sentiment'])
        for index, row in user_timeline_data.iteritems():
          sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(row)
          test = pad_sequences(sequence, maxlen=max_len)
          pred = model.predict(test)
          if pred[index] > 0.5:
            df.loc[index, ['Text']] = row
            df.loc[index, ['Sentiment']] = 'Positive'
            print(df.shape)
            print(pred)
          else:
            df.loc[index, ['Text']] = row
            df.loc[index, ['Sentiment']] = 'Negative'
            print(df.shape)
            print(pred)
            
          df.to_csv('sentiment_'+ screen_name +'.csv', index=False)
```

Error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-274fe2f3a8c0> in <module>()
     18           test = pad_sequences(sequence, maxlen=max_len)
     19           pred = model.predict(test)
---> 20           if pred[index] > 0.5:
     21             df.loc[index, ['Text']] = row
     22             df.loc[index, ['Sentiment']] = 'Positive'

IndexError: index 54 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 48
```

It would be great if someone can help me out

Answer (score 0):

The `index` variable you use on line 20 is the index of the row in `user_timeline_data.iteritems` it is not an index from the prediction. The prediction is most likely an array with only one value, since you only predict one instance. So change the `index` on line

```
if pred[index] > 0.5:
```

To

```
if pred[0] > 0.5:
```

Comment: Type pred: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
shape pred : (142, 1) and the shape changes for each row like(132,1),(142,1),(112,1) and do on. There are 10 files user_timeline_data having 200 rows each

Comment: Well that might be true for some iteration in your loop, but the error says it actually has shape  0 with size 48 (so (48,1)). The point is, the index var you use has nothing to do with the dimension of your pred array.

Comment: You should check if you get a prediction per word in the sequence instead of 1 for the whole sentence. Perhaps you pass the wrong shape to the predict function.

Comment: I changed sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(row) to sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([row]) and removed index in if pred condition and It worked.

Comment: Happy it works, if the answer helped you, please mark it as accepted.